# Qlik set analysis, partial selection of a field through modifier while ignoring the same fields selection

Tags: data-visualization, qlikview, qliksense, qlik-expression, set-analysis

I have fields, score, month, region and area. I need some of the score for maximum month. But my selection boxes have month, area and region.
On selection of month box the value changes although in modifier I have specified month to max month variable.
`Sum(1<month={"$maxmonth"},region=p(region),area=p(area)>score)` 
It still changes value when I select some other month.

Answer (score 2):

Your variable should be maxmonth = max({1}month). Then it will stop changing with your selections

Answer (score 0):

I have just figured out it is because of the variable for max month but I don't understand why is it happening. if I hard code the maximum month it works without any identifier

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out that my selections in the selection box were changing my variables value which in turn was changing the month fields modifier. I